# SSL enabled CiviCRM with forever loading dashlets?

Tags: dashboard

We had a CiviCRM installation where the dashlets worked fine...until...we configured Apache to forward all requests over 443 (https).

It seems that now an AJAX callback is failing (going directly to the callback leads to a "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment." error. The error details with debugging turned on state:

$Fatal Error Details = Array ( [callback] => Array ( [0] => CRM_Core_Error [1] => handle ) [code] => 0 [message] => [mode] => 16 [debug_info] => [type] => PEAR_Error [user_info] => [to_string] => [pear_error: message="" code=0 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info=""] )

Which is not terribly helpful for us who are not very familiar with the CiviCRM core.  Any ideas why this issue is occurring and/or what the fix might be?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Check your CiviCRM base URL - the CMS configuration (`$base_url` in Drupal settings.php), CiviCRM (`CIVICRM_UF_BASEURL` in civicrm.settings.php) and webserver configuration (canonical location you rewrite to) must all match.

For the dashboard to work, the webserver needs to be able to access the website itself.

If you're hosted at https://www.example.org the CiviCRM dashboard needs to be able to retrieve https://www.example.org/civicrm/report/instance/68 and so forth.

A webserver which can't access itself directly (reverse proxy, SSL, DNS may factor in) will fail loading the dashlets.

Same question, longer answer: [The dashboard does not render](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/the-dashboard-does-not-render/3430#3430)

Comment: I verified all of our settings (went into the config files, can hit something like https://www.example.org/civicrm/report/instance/68 from a browser on the box), and all seems to work.  Still, the dashlet is on a constant load.

Comment: From here, I'd recommend watching your webserver logs (PHP and webserver if separate) while loading the dashboard, and see if that gives any information. Note that the *lack* of a (successful) request may be information as well!

Answer (score 1):

Chris' suggestion to check your Base URL is a good one - I'd also check **Administer menu > System Settings > Resource URLs**, because if they're misconfigured you'll see similar issues.

Comment: All of the settings are correct. But, thanks for your entry because it did lead me to this topic: https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=6090.0 . I'm getting an error when I use the simple curl request script " Connected to example.org (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 443 (#0)
* Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
* skipping SSL peer certificate verification
* NSS: client certificate not found (nickname not specified)
* NSS error -12227 (SSL_ERROR_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ALERT)
... so, does CiviCRM rely on NSS for a client PKI cert (we have 2way SSL on)

Comment: Cheryl - that deserves to be asked as its own question so it gets more attention!

Answer (score 0):

There was also the issue [CRM-16035: Dashlet refresh *can* crash server - replace use of HTTP_Request](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-16035) recently, but what you describe doesn't sound like that.

Comment: Agreed.  Hitting this directly: https://www.example.org/civicrm/ajax/dashboard?op=get_widget&key=fc010d2bf22156d7d81cd385a7dd9954&id=1#overlay-context=user/1 (so shouldn't have a multiple thread issue) fails