# Does anyone use CiviCRM behind a Web Application Firewall?

Tags: security, sysadmin

We're looking at deployment for a client who's sensitive to being hacked, so we want to put CiviCRM behind, say, nginx running mod_security2.  Has anyone used a WAF with CiviCRM that can share recommendations?

Answer (score 5):

we have a slightly different approach for an enhanced security architecture using a proxy-server plus vpn. If you are interested, please sind more information plus code on [GitHub](https://github.com/systopia/CiviProxy), there was also a [session](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JKNR0bDjB9k) on last year's CiviCon.

Let me know if you have any questions regarding CiviProxy.

Kind Regards
Fabian

Answer (score 1):

I've configured CiviCRM behind both [Pound](http://www.apsis.ch/pound/) and [NginX](http://nginx.org/). Both worked perfectly well, no complaints. If there were any special configurations required, they can't have been troublesome enough to remember :)

You will need to ensure CiviCRM is capable of "accessing itself", since some requests (eg dashboard contents) are made to the current CiviCRM website. This includes DNS / web access from the webserver CiviCRM is running on - see [this answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/ssl-enabled-civicrm-with-forever-loading-dashlets/4453#4453).