# Webfaction hosting, behind a proxy - broken dashlet

Tags: dashboard

Webfaction hosted servers are behind firewalls/proxies. Unlike standing up apache (i.e., socket:xxxx on localhost), their wordpress installation appears to simply be the wordpress code. Therefore, they appear to application route the WP requests vs. NAT/firewall the TCP.

I would guess the civicrm plugin doesn't pass "HOST:" http headers ...

yes, no, solutions? (see pict)

Note:specific menu items (e.g., Administer-> System Settings -> Option Groups) render fine. (and, that messed up CSS is probably due to the 404 page's css)

[image: Wordpress, Civicrm admin page on Webfaction]

Answer (score 3):

At least until the most recent 4.7 releases, CiviCRM needed to contact itself via http to populate the dashboard. Your picture suggests that it's not able to, probably related to how the proxy is setup. If you have a command line interface in environment that the code is executing, see if you can contact yourself using, say curl or wget. Sometimes hardcoding the domain in /etc/hosts is a solution.

Another way to mess up your dashboard is with a slightly broken certificate on a https only site - some will render for you in Chrome, but curl/wget won't like it. But in that case, you'd get a spinning thingy.

Comment: Hardcoding the domain in /etc/hosts and/or upgrading is definitely the correct answer!

Comment: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4448/ssl-enabled-civicrm-with-forever-loading-dashlets/4453#4453 and https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/the-dashboard-does-not-render/3430#3430 might be worth a reference if you decide to not go the upgrade route.