# Is there a bug in Follow-up activity search?

Tags: activities, search, issues

Is there a bug in Follow-up activity search?

1. I open Advanced search > Activities
2. Choose: **Has a Followup Activity?** = Yes
3. Click Search
4. Result = Error

Also tested in CiviCRM Drupal sandbox.

[image]

Option **Is a Followup Activity?** seems to work OK.

Comment: if you could enable debugging and backtrace (Administer > System Settings > Debugging and Error Handling) this will include a hyperlink with additional details about the error - copy and paste the details of the error into a post and that might provide someone out here with enough information to point you in the right direction.

Comment: That would be problematic, because my Dashboards are frozen (loading eternally) and enabling Debugging and Backtrace itself immediately generates an error.

Comment: Hmmm - that doesn't sound very good at all - you may need to reach out to the person who implemented the system to help you with more technical related issues. This doesn't sound like something that can be fixed without digging into your logs, and this isn't quite the forum for that. Good luck!

Comment: It is on the queue. I suspect it could be this error: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3426/the-dashboard-does-not-render

I think Debugging and Backtrace is giving the error messages for these stuck Dashboards.